# Problem with finding out loged user

Tags: development, asp.net

I try to write a procedure, which find out is the user logged or not not loged in the service. I write a code. But it sometimes giving me a true or false if not a person shown. Sometimes it gives me true or false. Please help me what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
   public bool sprawdzanieUserow()
    {
        SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPUserCollection usersAll = witryna.SiteUsers;
        foreach (SPUser oUserPrivilages usersAll)
        {
            if (oUserPrivilages.Name == "Jan Kowalski" || oUserPrivilages.Name == "Wojciech Kowalczyk")
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } // Koniec sprawdzania userów
```

Comment: I get ready with this:

`        public bool sprawdzanieUserow()
        {
            SPWeb site = SPContext.Current.Web;
            int managerGroup = site.Groups["Właściciele witryny Main"].ID;
            if (site.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(managerGroup))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }`

Comment: The code from your comment will return true, if current user is in the managerGroup. From the question, I thought you wanted to know if Jan Kowalski or Wojciech Kowalczyk are browsing the site or not. So, which one is it?

Comment: It's whot I needed, but Cant describe it in english